# Completed 401 Unauthorized after updating password with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise, http-status-code-401

When I try to update the user password I have :

> > Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

The update happen properly but then I'm logged out. I would like to stay log after this update.

I use the `update with password` method from devise.

**Registrations_controller**

```
 def update_password
    @user = current_user
    authorize @user, :update?
    if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
      flash[:success] = t 'edit.success'
    else
      flash[:error] = t 'flash.error_occured'
    end
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path + "##{t('users.account.title')}"
  end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :current_password, :password, :email, :username )
end
```

view code:

```
  = form_for @user, url: update_password_path, html: { method: :put, role: 'form'} do |f|
    = devise_error_messages!

    = f.label t ('password.current')
    = f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: :off

    = f.label t('password.new')
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: :off

    = f.submit t('button.change'), data: { disable_with: t('ajaxdoing') }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `update` action to something like this

```
def update_password
  @user = current_user
  authorize @user, :update?
  if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
    sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
    flash[:success] = t 'edit.success'
  else
    flash[:error] = t 'flash.error_occured'
  end
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path + "##{t('users.account.title')}"
end
```

EDIT:

Devise logs out automatically when password is updated so we can not escape that, instead we are logging in the user again and bypassing warder callbacks.

Comment: It works thank you ! Can you give me a little explanation about that ? Why is it logging out in this case ? When I update other part of my user account it doesn't do that.